# Step to pass "-std=c++11" flag in gdb regression test-suite setup

Tags: c++11, gdb, dejagnu

I am trying to run GDB testsuite with "-std=c++11" flag for the subtest case under "gdb.cp" folder or for the CPP related test-cases.

Currently I am performing it using DejaGnu directive "dg-options" in CPP test-case like :

**// { dg-options "-std=c++11" }**

But I am not confirm whether this is right way or not. Because if I check the gdb.log file, I am not seeing "-std=c++11" flag passed at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be, from the top-level build directory, to run the tests like:

```
make check-gdb RUNTESTFLAGS="CXX_FOR_TARGET='g++ --std=c++11' gdb.cp/*.exp"
```

GDB also supports CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET which can be set in the same way, despite being called CFLAGS these flags are appended for any compile, so you'll start to see warnings/errors about `--std=c++11` being an invalid option for C tests, etc.

A final option that might be of interest would be creating a whole new DeJaGNU board file which would override the compiler flags, however, I couldn't get this working so quickly, so your mileage may vary.

You can find more information about running the tests here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/TestingGDB

Comment: I am able to pass "c++11" flag through dejagnnu board file, which override the compiler flags for whole gdb test-suite.          But can't i simply added "dg-options" directives in the CPP test-cases and run for individual only like:                                         // { dg-options "-std=c++11" }

Comment: ->Specify additional compiler options : 
{ dg-options options [{ target selector }] }
This DejaGnu directive provides a list of compiler options, to be used if the target system matches selector, that replace the default options used for this set of tests.

Comment: The dg framework is not used by GDB, you either need to set compiler flags globally, or in each test's exp file.  The dg system makes sense for GCC where all tests are basically the same - compile this thing, then either examine the final assembler, or run the final binary, GDB tests do many different things in each test.  So for GCC we might use `dg-runtest` with a list of source files, and embed dg directives in each source file, in GDB each test is its own exp file which contains instructions for what to do in that test.  Common functionality lives in `lib/gdb.exp` and friends.